# How to call a function on a class variable?

Tags: php

In my PHP class, I'd like to declare a private static variable `$filePath` and assign it to the value returned by `dirname(__FILE__)`. Here's my code:

```
class MyClass {
   private static $filePath = dirname(__FILE__);
}
```

PHP returns an error: *`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'`*. What can be the issue and how can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: You can't assign dynamic values to a class member `this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.`

Comment: If you want to assign a dynamic value, assign it within `__construct()` instead.

Comment: Thank you. My concern is that it is redundant if each instance of class will initialize the static variable $filePath to the exactly same value. Is there a more efficient approach to this? A static function that handles initialization?

Comment: @Alex it is possible to declare a constant outside your class for use inside the class: `define('FILE_PATH',dirname(__FILE__));` and then inside your class: `private static $filePath = FILE_PATH;` Note that this approach is inappropriate for the question of which this one was marked a duplicate, but is acceptable in your context.